# When does Unity3D's Plattform dependent compilation work?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, dependencies, platform

I have a small code snippet here from one of my projects. It is used in the script for a drag and drop menu. The script is attached to every item, that is dragable.

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData){
    if (isPlantLocked())
        return;

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    #endif

    #if UNITY_ANDROID
        transform.position = Input.touches[0].position;
    #endif
}
```

I get an exception (every frame i drag the item), that Input.touches.Length is zero, but this code region should only be used on android, and on the mobile version everything works fine.

And now my question is how can i get rid of the exception and when does the plattform dependency work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your "Build Settings" window, there is a "Switch Platform" button that'll adjust your current runtime platform and trigger compilation of the respective directives, even while in the editor.  This means both `UNITY_ANDROID` and `UNITY_EDITOR` can both be `true` at the same time because `UNITY_EDITOR` means you're running in the Unity application itself.

Since you're checking input types and the first one is for a mouse, you might want to replace `UNITY_EDITOR` with `UNITY_STANDALONE` and then make sure that when you're testing in the editor, you have the correct current platform set.

Another option (better if you're never going to publish a standalone build and it's only intended for non-PC platforms) would be to first check against `UNITY_EDITOR` and then `#else if` into the other options:

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
    transform.position = Input.touches[0].position;
#endif
```

This way you can be a little more lax with swapping out your current platform setting.

Answer (score 1):

When you are in **Editor**, and **Android** platform is selected in the build settings, both of those codes will work.

if you don't want to execute specific **Android** code in **Editor**, you could do the following:

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData){
if (isPlantLocked())
    return;

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
#endif

#if UNITY_ANDROID && !UNITY_EDITOR
    transform.position = Input.touches[0].position;
#endif}
```

You can also read more about this [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html).